# Thread pool in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, threadpool

What are my options for creating ThreadPool in native c++ using Visual Studio 2012?
Are there any builtin types in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thread Pool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) probably has the information you're looking for. Specifically [CreateThreadpool function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the function for creating thread pools. Documentation for the original thread pool api (Windows 2000) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is this API restricted to Windows Vista or later?

Comment: @Tudor The one I linked originally is Windows Vista or later. The second one I just added has some information about the original API.